# Error connecting to windows cluster

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2016, failovercluster

We currently have 6 MSSQL (SQL2016 Enterprise) servers running on Windows server 2016. We are running windows failover cluster and always on availability.

Last weekend we had an issue with the failover cluster. The failover cluster server had to be restarted for everything to come back to normal. Still investigating what caused this.

So everything came back up and running normally. The issue we are seeing is 5 out of the 6 sql servers can not access the Windows failover cluster via the gui.

Basically when trying to connect we see "An error occurred connecting to the cluster"

"Access is denied"

What is weird everything is working fine and as I said one for the servers is able to access it and shows everything up and running. Not sure why the other servers can not connect to it. I am using the same user to try and connect from the servers that dont work with the server that does work.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this or what might be going on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: And the cluster log?

Comment: Cluster log shows the same thing. error connecting to cluster.
System.ApplicationException: An error occurred trying to display the cluster information. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I've the exact same issue on WS2019 for a cluster with FSRM, for just one of the nodes.